# openURL not being called from mail app

Tags: ios, email, openurl

I want to be able to have my app called from the email app when the users selects to open an attachment with a custom URL.  It seems that IOS does recognize the registration but still does not call the application delegate to open the URL.

I've registered my app to support a custom URL by adding this to info.plist;

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>TecNotes Data File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.bringardner.textext</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>testext</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/vnd.testext+xml</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This is the code for the application delegate;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Override point for customization after application launch.
if( launchOptions == nil) {
    NSLog(@"nil options");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Have options");
    NSObject *obj = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    NSLog(@"url? %@",obj);
}

 return YES;
}

-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
NSLog(@"handle %@",url);
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"open %@",url);

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"willFinishLaunchingWithOptions ");
    return YES;
}
```

Prior to adding the entries in info.plist I get the following message from the email app;
[image: email error]
After adding entries to info.plist the email application opens a blank page but none of the application delegate methods are called.
[image: After image]

I've seen several similar questions but nothing I've attempted has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has extension *.testext whereas in UTI definition above i see .textext Also, I was able to implement custom UTI using the airdrop sample https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type-o.  I corrected that so that everywhere is consistent (.testext) but the behavior does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow airdrop sample above. It has almost everything to make it working. That's what i followed and it worked perfectly for me. Let me know if it doesn't work I can paste more info

Answer (score 0):

When an email attachment is opened in your app, the method `application:openURL:options` is called, not `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`.